# Padding left in Bootstrap Option Select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a drop down option list. The user will choose a paper format but I want to show the size of the name next to the name but I want it tabbed for readability. Is it poosible?

```
<select class="selectpicker">
<option>A4 210x279mm</option>
<option>A5 210x148mm</option>
<option>Letter 216x280mm</option>
</select>
```

I want the size part to start at the same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only by hiding the `<select>` and drawing your own set of DOM elements based on the contents of `<select>` and passing back the user interaction to the `<select>`. That's how all the `select` syling UI libraries did it for the past... actually, ever since people wanted to style up `<select>`s and `<option>`s cross browser.

You won't find one `select` styling library in the history of web who did it any other way.

You're looking at [`Select2`](https://select2.github.io/), [`Chosen`](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), [`Bootstrap dropdown`](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp), [`Angular Material Select`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select) ... the list is quite long.

Comment: Doesnt it work if I count the number of letters in each option and add whitespaces accordingly? I populate from an array.

Comment: It definitely would work, if you are willing to use a `monospaced` font, where all characters have equal width. Are you open to this type of trade-off?

Comment: No :-). I am actally not :-)

Comment: Some of the libraries I linked provide the possibility of building your own template for the select item. That's your only option at this point. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could right align the text, if you're okay with the paper type not being flush to the left.

```
select.selectpicker > option {
  text-align: right;
}
```

To be perfectly aligned down to the pixel you may need to use a monospace font.

Comment: Thank you for the input but I dont want the text right aligned.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need select.  Andrei said it rightly there is none.  You can use a ul tag and style the li elements and use jquery to populate selected value in an hidden input field and then process it accordingly.

Comment: I would definitely not go with `<ul>`. I hate having to style against the default *unordered list* browser default styling, when I have the option of using elements that have `display:block;` out of the box. Welcome to [so].

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is a bit over my talent.

Comment: Thank you Andrei for your words. I look down upon it as well but considering he needed a styling solution,  I only meant this as one of the workarounds.